# Form fields stability php

Tags: php, forms, validation

How can I make fields still in the form fields after submitting the form and return with invalid input data?

```
 <form action="" method="post">
             <label for="cellPhoneNo">البريد الالكتروني</label>
                <input type="text" name="emailAddress" class="textField"/>
                <span>*</span>
                <span><?php 
                       if($emailValidator != CORRECT_VALUE)
                        echo $errorMessage[$emailValidator];?>
                </span>
                <br>

</form>
```

and here's where I check the input

```
 $emailValidator=checkInput($_POST['emailAddress'],INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS,'/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/');
```

when user submit invalid email address, the validation result shows the error message to user. How can I make the invalid error email address still in the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to input

```
 <input type="text" name="emailAddress" class="textField" value="<?  echo (isset($_POST) ? $_POST['emailAddress'] : "") ?>"/>
```

instead of "" you can insert your default value or just leave it like this :)

Answer (score 1):

Try,

`<input type="text" name="emailAddress" value="<?php echo $_POST['emailAddress']; ?>" class="textField"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use javascript to validate the email before posting it to your server-side code :)

Check this link: http://www.zparacha.com/validate-email-address-using-javascript-regular-expression/

Comment: Or you could use the solution @mkk suggested :)

Comment: I usually depends on the server on form validation, it's more secure.

Comment: Sure is. I suggest both client- and server-side validation :)